# How can i get the DD/MM/YYYY formar in my datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, datepicker

im from spain and i need to put the DD/MM/YYYY format in my datepicker, here is the code

```html
<br>

<label for="from">Inicio de castigo </label>
<div class='input-group date' id='from'>
  <input type='text' id="from" name="from" class="form-control" readonly />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>

<br>

<label for="to">Final de castigo </label>
<div class='input-group date' id='to'>
  <input type='text' name="to" id="to" class="form-control" readonly />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>

<br>





<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#from').datetimepicker({

      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      maxViewMode: 0,
      language: 'es',
      daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
      todayHighlight: true,
      minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
      pickTime: false

    });
    $('#to').datetimepicker({

      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      maxViewMode: 0,
      language: 'es',
      daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
      todayHighlight: true,
      minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
      pickTime: false
    });

  });
</script>
```

I put in the script the MM-DD-YYYY fromat but when i pick the calendar he gives me the MM-DD-YYYY format, that is the uk hour. Today is 07 of June of 2017, and when i open it, it says that is 6 of July 2017. How can i solve that? It can be a problem of the datetimepicker.es.js files? . Thanks for the help guys :)

I have more information in that file, there are all the scripts i use

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$base_url?>js/es-ES.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$base_url?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$base_url?>js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$base_url?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$base_url?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=$base_url?>css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="<?=$base_url?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.es.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are using `format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'` change it

Answer (score 0):

Change  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY' To format: 'DD/MM/YYYY':

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#from').datetimepicker({   

               format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                maxViewMode: 0,
                language: 'es',
                daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
                todayHighlight: true,               
                minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
                pickTime: false

            });
            $('#to').datetimepicker({

                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',           
                maxViewMode: 0,
                language: 'es',
                daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
                todayHighlight: true,
                minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
                pickTime: false
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('.datepicker').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' });
    jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your code and shorten it like this:

```
$('#from, #to').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      maxViewMode: 0,
      language: 'es',
      daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
      todayHighlight: true,
      minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
      pickTime: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed there is a mistake in your code that it could be affecting:

```html
 <div class='input-group date' id='from'>
                        <input type='text' id="from" name="from" class="form-control" readonly  />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <label for="to">Final de castigo </label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='to'>
                        <input type='text' name="to" id="to" class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </div>
```

Here you are using twice the id "from" and the id "to". The id value must to be unique. It should be only one in all the code. And in this case it should be in the div with the class 'input-group'.

Look this example:

```html
  <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker1'>
               <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Select preferred meeting date"/>
               <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
               </span>
           </div>
```

After that you can choose the format of the datepicker by the next javascript code:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datepicker1').datetimepicker({
                      viewMode: 'days',
                      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

This should work perfectly. I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried it but its the same problem. it gets that we are in july because is the 7 day, and gets the day 6 because we are in june. I dont know here is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<br>        
<label for="from">Inicio de castigo </label>
<div class='input-group date' id='from'>
    <input type='text' id="from" name="from" class="form-control datepicker" readonly  />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>

<br>

<label for="to">Final de castigo </label>
<div class='input-group date' id='to'>
    <input type='text' name="to" id="to" class="form-control datepicker" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>

<br>




  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script></p>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        maxViewMode: 0,
        language: 'es',
        daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
        todayHighlight: true,
        minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
        pickTime: false
    });
  } );
</script>
```